# Affine smooth variety has only trivial first-order deformations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, deformation-theory

Does someone have a quick and direct argument that infinitesimal deformations of an affine smooth variety over a field $k$ are only the trivial infinitesimal deformations? (without previous construction of the functors $T^i$ of the cotangent complex)

Comment: This follows from the fact that smooth morphisms satisfy the infinitesimal lifting property. For affine schemes over a field this is shown in Hartshornes book on deformation theory. For the general case, see EGAIV. Once you know that the infinitesimal lifting property holds, the argument is quite simple. See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322093/why-does-infinitesimal-lifting-imply-triviality-of-infinitesimal-deformations/)

Comment: Just to add to @Rieux's ice comment, the liftings exist affine locally and the existence of a global lifting is classified by a coherent cohomology group. It is the vanishing of such a group which guarantees such a global lifting for affine schemes. One might want to check Illusie's article in Hodge Theory for more details.

Comment: @ Alex Youcis: Dear Alex thanks for the interesting answer. Actually the reason why I wanted to have a direct argument for affines wich do not rely on cohomology is to then do the following "locally you have a trivialization of deformations, these trivializations produce a cocycle wich is easily seen to live in the $H¹$ of the tangent bundle". So actually I wanted this local triviality to show the correspondence you mention with cohomology.