# Projective space has no non-trivial first order deformations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, deformation-theory

A first order deformation is a deformation over the dual numbers $k[t]/(t^2)$. I have read that there are no non-trivial first order deformations of complex projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ (i.e. no first order deformations other than $\mathbb{P}^n\times \operatorname{Spec} k[t]/(t^2)\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k[t]/(t^2)$).

I am aware of the result for affine smooth schemes (for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322093/why-does-infinitesimal-lifting-imply-triviality-of-infinitesimal-deformations?noredirect=1&lq=1)) using the infinitesimal lifting property, but am not sure how to approach this for $\mathbb{P}^n$, perhaps we use the cohomology of line bundles on $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Question: Why are there no non-trivial first order deformations on $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: The deformations of a smooth algebraic variety $X$ over $k[t]/(t^2)$ are parametrised by $H^1(X,T_X)$ where $T_X$ is the tangent bundle of $X$. For $X=\mathbb{P}^n$ this sheaf cohomology vanishes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_(mathematics).

Comment: @Kapil why are they paramterized by $H^1(X,T_X)$?

Comment: @Kapil that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?

Comment: @DeekshaAlisetty that is a theorem which holds for any nonsingular variety $ X $. For details, look at Hartshorne's book on deformation theory.